# How to set target version the ResourceWriter class creates in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm using the Resources.ResourceWriter class to prepare a resource file for use in another program. **That program targets .net 2.0**, but the resource file created contains **DLL and bitmap references targeting 4.0.** How can I control which target version the ResourceWriter class creates? I understand that I may need to use a TypeNameConverter, but I can't seem to find any info on how to use this with a ResourceWriter. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: @SujithKarivelil, [please do not add salutations to any questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/209031). In fact, you should try to remove them during edit suggestions.